# What is the cost for a reload of F4 Fusion Block missiles?

Tags: weapons, savage-worlds

In the Rifts for Savage Worlds setting, in the Tomorrow Legion Players Guide, page 83, there is a suit of Power Armor, the Triax T-31 Super Trooper. One of its weapons are missile launchers that only shoot the F4 Fusion Block Missiles:

> 2×Rocket  Launchers  (shoulders). They only fire the F4 Fusion Block missiles (Range 15/30/60, Damage 6d6, RoF 1, AP 25, Mega Damage, SBT). Each launcher has two missiles

These missiles are consumable (obviously). A player in my game has this armor, and wishes to purchase additional missiles to reload. Having searched my PDF of this book, the GM Handbook, and the Savage Foes of North America book, I have come to the conclusion that *these missiles have no listed cost.*

So, question number 1: **Have I missed the obvious here? Do these missiles have a listed cost in a book?**

Assuming I am correct and that there is no cost, we will need to make use of the rest of the material to craft an appropriate cost.

Savage Rifts follows a simple system where more powerful armaments are more expensive.

There already is a system for changing missiles from "anti-personnel" to "anti-vehicle" (TMPG 91), which reduces damage by one die type, and raises AP by 5.

It appears no stats perfectly line up with the F4 Fusion Block missiles. The Medium Missile Launcher goes from 8d6 damage with AP 15 to 7d6 damage with AP 20. Applying this again would get us to 6d6 damage with AP 25. Thus, it seems reasonable for the F4 Fusion Block Missiles to cost the same as Medium Missiles ($10,000/missile), plus a potential rarity or specialty markup.

So, **is this cost reasonable, and does it follow the design presented in the material?** (or, at least close enough that my players won't raise eyebrows at it)

N.B. the F4 Fusion Block missiles have their burst size reduced from a Medium template to a Small Template. However, they have the distinct extra advantage of "sticking" to a target and can be later detonated "by hand, voice command, on impact, or after a timed delay (from 3 to 30 seconds) set by the pilot."

Incidentally, I have a similar question for the other consumable weapon on this mech, the MAE-3, but the player hasn't asked for a reload of those yet.

> 3×MAE-3 (“Maysies”) Hand Charges. The Maysies are thrown or placed (Range 5/10/20, Damage 3d8, RoF 1, AP 10, Mega Damage, SBT)

Comment: Huh, I was unable to create the tag "savage-rifts" (don't have enough reputation). This appears to be the first Savage Rifts question on the site.

Comment: Is there a general "cost of operation" for the suit that might cover expended ammunition?

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon: Good thought, but no, ammo capacities seem to be universally spelled out, and upkeep and repair is represented by "technical difficulties" (TLPG p.122-123). For example, a reload of the Boom Gun's shots, the primary weapon of another mecha, costs 30,000 (TLPG p.89). In the GM Guide p.81 it says that Tomorrow Legion members are provided ammo reloads as part of their salary, but in the game I'm running, they're not "full members" and wouldn't receive that benefit (yet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Fusion Missile has the same cost as a Light Missile ($3K each), and the MAE-3 costs the same as a High Explosive Grenade at $750.

Source: I'm the Savage Worlds Brand Manager and official answer guy.